# Adjust given date range and interpolate values

Tags: excel, vba, date, range, interpolation

Good afternoon,

I have a data set, which contains reporting dates and various parameters corresponding with this date. Each parameter provides a value related to the duration between the reports. So, the set contains multiple rows with the same date (but different time), and could contain a single row for which values are applicable to multiple dates.

Example of the set listed below:

```
Date                Distance    Price
02-01-2018 04:00    370         26.71
03-01-2018 04:00    357         27.31
04-01-2018 04:00    376         23.47
04-01-2018 04:48    8           0.72
04-01-2018 05:36    0           0.19
05-01-2018 04:00    328         23.77
05-01-2018 17:30    202         15.23
07-01-2018 17:13    7           1.54
08-01-2018 05:00    0           7.44
09-01-2018 05:00    0           3.89
10-01-2018 04:00    333         21.38
10-01-2018 11:00    110         6.40
```

What i would like to get:

```
Date                Distance covered    Price
02-01-2018 04:00    370                 26.71
03-01-2018 04:00    357                 27.31
04-01-2018 04:00    376                 23.47
05-01-2018 04:00    336                 24.67
06-01-2018 04:00    204                 15.56
07-01-2018 04:00    4                   0.77
08-01-2018 04:00    2                   7.24
09-01-2018 04:00    0                   3.93
10-01-2018 04:00    333                 21.55
11-01-2018 04:00    110                 6.40
```

I want to be able to choose a start date/time, and create a macro which automatically creates 24hr intervals after this date till the end of data set and interpolates the parameters.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Could you please provide the code of what you have tried so far? *(Otherwise it is a nicely formatted question, at least props for that)*

Comment: You can use macro recorder to explore the beginnings of coding this. Though you will quickly want to tidy that up!